# ASP.NET "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" occurs also with configured servicepointmanager

Tags: vb.net, ssl, .net-4.5, webrequest, servicepoint

I'm trying to request this image: https://www.kamerstunt.nl/file/img/web/woning/9577323WenumWieselZwolseweg-142d_6.jpg
If the image no longer exists when you read this, it might have been removed, but you'd still be able to view the SSL certificate in question. Using my browser I was able to successfully navigate to the page, request the image and see a valid SSL certificate.

I checked here: [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822509/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

So I added that solution to my code:

```
Dim imgRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.kamerstunt.nl/file/img/web/woning/9577323WenumWieselZwolseweg-142d_6.jpg")
Dim imgResponse As WebResponse
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls 
'//I also tried: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
imgResponse = imgRequest.GetResponse()
Dim streamPhoto As Stream = imgResponse.GetResponseStream()
```

I tried:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

But then I get errors:
`'Tls12' is not a member of 'System.Net.SecurityProtocolType'` and 
`'Tls11' is not a member of 'System.Net.SecurityProtocolType'`

I also tried to change the registry to allow windows to not block DHE with 512 bits and added ClientMinKeyBitLength with 0x00000200(512) value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman.`

But still it fails...why?

Comment: Are you wanting to download the file is that it?

Comment: I'm trying to load it into a memorystream (so not to disk): `Dim streamPhoto As Stream = imgResponse.GetResponseStream()`

Comment: Please see updated answer...it's tried and tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I use that returns a `Stream`... You can also modify it so it returns a byte array and then create a new MemoryStream from that byte array. Also instead of a string type to pass you can change it to a url, but that's up to you.

```
Public Function GetRemoteStream(uRL As String) As MemoryStream
   Dim webClient As New WebClient()
   Dim imageBytes As Byte() = webClient.DownloadData(uRL)
   Dim mem As New MemoryStream(imageBytes)
   Return mem
End Function
```

**Example Usage**

```
 Dim nStream As New MemoryStream
 nStream = GetRemoteStream(yoururlhere)
```

**EDIT PLEASE READ** ********************************************

After looking into this and digging a little further, I found a solution. It seem's that the site has dropped support for SSL & Tls11.

I started a new project targeting **4.5 framework**. I then used this `SecurityProtocolType`...

```
 SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

**Solution**

Change the target framework to: **4.5** and use: **SecurityProtocolType.Tls12**.
Now your protocol should look like this...

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

**On another note**

I recommend wrapping your `Stream`so it get's properly disposed of. For example:

```
Using stream As Stream = imgResponse.GetResponseStream()
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Dim count As Integer = 0
                Do
                    Dim buf As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
                    count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024)
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count)
                Loop While stream.CanRead AndAlso count > 0
                'ms is your memory stream... as I take it you want the photo :)
            End Using
        End Using
```

Here's proof of my output...

[image]

Comment: On your code line `Dim imageBytes As Byte() = webClient.DownloadData(uRL)` I get the error `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.`

Comment: In your servicepointmanager can you try this? `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Comment: Using that I get 2 errors: `'Tls11' is not a member of 'SecurityProtocolType'.` and `'Tls12' is not a member of 'SecurityProtocolType'.` The others I already tried (see code comment in my original post). What else could it be?

Comment: Thanks. I looked into changing the target framework, but am having issues with that...please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190394/asp-net-the-targetframework-attribute-is-not-allowed. How would I go about changing the targetframework for a website project?

Comment: Change it at project level..? `Right click on project --> Properties --> Application --> Target Framework` change that...