# Using HttpClient & HttpWebRequest for Https TLS1.2

Tags: c#, tls1.2

In Console Application, while trying to hit the "https" Endpoint configured with TLS 1.2.

In C#
While using HttpClient I am getting the success response from endpoint

```
       HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        //specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("HTTPSENDPOINT");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent("POSTDATA");
        var task = httpClient.PostAsync("/Token", content);

        task.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine(task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString());
```

But when using HttpWebRequest

```
       var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("HTTPSENDPOINT/Token");
       var postData = "POSTDATA";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) // Getting Error in GetRequestStream() method call
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting below error

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong while using HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822509/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: @AndreSilva - I have tried with SSL3 also but the same error is happening in HttpWebRequest but not in HttpClient.

Comment: I didn't test that, but try to set `SecurityProtocol` **before** calling `WebRequest.Create`.

Comment: @Youssef13 - I have tried the way you suggested and its working fine. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `SecurityProtocol` property **before** calling `WebRequest.Create` method.

**Update:**

Let me add some details that explain why this should be correct.

Having a look at the source code of `WebRequest.Create(string)` method from [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs,6216de40b052b741,references).

The return value is:

```cs
return Create(new Uri(requestUriString), false);
```

so now, Let's take a look at `Create(Uri, bool)` method, it returns some object from `WebRequestPrefixElement.Creator.Create(Uri)`.

`Creator` is a property inside of `WebRequestPrefixElement` and it's of type `IWebRequestCreate`.
In your case, `IWebRequestCreate` will be an `HttpRequestCreator` object.

Looking at the code of `HttpRequestCreator.Create` method:

```cs
public WebRequest Create( Uri Uri ) {
    //
    // Note, DNS permissions check will not happen on WebRequest
    //
    return new HttpWebRequest(Uri, null);
}
```

Finally, Let's look at that `HttpWebRequest` constructor.
You'll see a long code there, but really what is important is this line:

```cs
SslProtocols = (SslProtocols)ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;
```

so the `SecurityProtocol` value is assigned to a property called `SslProtocols`.
So, it's obvious now that `SecurityProtocol` is used and kind of saved to the HttpWebRequest object when you call `Create` method, so changing `SecurityProtocol` **after** calling `Create` will not change the protocol used by the HttpWebRequest object.

Comment: All my suffering and googling because I had the order of 2 lines reversed... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seem really close to this problem [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822509/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

I noticed that they had a problem with not adding SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 with the other ones you already added. Try to implement the enum protocol as what the top rated answer did.